# nivo slider - not appearing in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

front end design is my weak spot so im a bit lost.

The nivo slider for this site(www.myfriendshotel.com) im working on is working fine in firefox but not in ie.
The only reason on google why it wouldnt work is the styling not being closed properly but I have checked all of that.

any ideas ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off.

The solution was too clean all the html as unnecessary tags were lingering and also to cleanup all the js and then all was well again!

Comment: how did you do it?  I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

IE was probably switching to compatibility mode ..

I had that problem with Nivo...

to disable compatibilty mode :

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Encounter this issue today and added your suggestion to the page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change nivo slider CSS with:

```
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {

      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      border:0;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      z-index:6000;
      display:none;
      /*patch IE10*/
      background:white;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      opacity: 0; 

}
```